# ¿Cómo optimizo la escritura a un archivo que recibirá miles o millones de entradas en C++?

Tags: c++, array, archivo

mi problema es el siguiente: estoy usando un programa en c++ que realiza una búsqueda y la devuelve por pantalla como una linea de texto. Lo modifiqué para que realice la misma operación de forma iterativa y escriba el resultado a un archivo de texto, con cada linea separada por un salto de linea. Cuando se tienen pocos registros, la operacion la realizo abriendo y escribiendo la línea nueva al archivo y cerrándolo después. El problema es si tienes 10 millones de registros, me imagino que hay una sobrecarga al hacerlo de esta manera. Entonces, que puede ser mas optimo:

1. Seguir haciéndolo de esta manera.
2. Almacenar cada resultado en un vector y luego de que contenga “n” elementos volcarlo a un archivo.

Si opto por la segunda opcion, una alternativa seria usar un for simple para recorrer el vector y escribir cada elemento como una linea nueva al archivo, pero aunque lo abriré al principio del for y lo cerrare al salir, ¿no seria similar a la opción (1), en cuanto a recarga y uso del disco? ¿Existe una forma de hacerlo de manera más automática?
¿Y se se pasa el contenido “n” del vector a una variable de tipo string (¿cuál es el tamaño máximo?) o similar y luego se vuelca esta variable al archivo, la escritura se haría  solo una vez? ¿Mejoraría el proceso?.

Muchas gracias

Comment: No acabo de entender el escenario. El archivo con muchas líneas ¿es el origen de los datos (es decir: lo usarás para leer) o es el destino de los datos (es decir: escribirás ahí)? ¿o es ambas cosas a la vez?

Comment: El archivo con muchos registros es el resultado de la busqueda y es guardado en el disco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para un mayor rendimiento:

- Reducir el número de llamadas al sistema.
- No abrir y cerrar el archivo ni llamar la función `flush` constantemente.
- Si se almacena temporalmente la información en un buffer, más grande mejor. Cuánto más pequeño más llamadas al sistema necesitará.

Eso sí, no podrás superar la velocidad del disco.

---

Entonces, una posibilidad es ir guardando algo de información en un buffer y escribir su contenido cuando se llene.

Se me ocurre que podrías crear una clase como esta para ayudarte. Es un poco simple pero te da una idea de cómo funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <int BufSize>
class FileWriter {
    char buffer[BufSize];
    int offset;
    FILE* file;
    
public:
    FileWriter(string path){
        offset = 0;
        file = fopen(path);
    }

    ~FileWriter(){
        if (file){
            apply();
            fclose(file);
        }
    }

    void write(const void * data, int size){
        auto charData = (const char*)data;

        // Si la información entrante ocupa un tamaño mayor al del
        // buffer se escribe directamente al archivo
        if (size >= BufSize){
            apply();
            fwrite(charData, 1, size, file);
            return;
        }

        int available = BuffSize - offset;

        // Para no complicar el código, se escribe el contenido
        // cuando no haya espacio para almacenar la información actual
        if (available < size)
            apply();
            
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            charData[offset + i] = data[i];

        offset += size;  
    }

private:
    void apply(){
        if (offset <= 0)
            return;

        fwrite(buffer, 1, offset, file);
        offset = 0;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver que decidí usar las [funciones de C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c) para abrir, cerrar y escribir al archivo. Pero puedes usar [las de C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) o incluso no crear una clase para el proceso si prefieres.

La idea sería que la instancia viva desde que comiences hasta que termines trabajar con el archivo.

Sugiero que pruebes el código con algunos megabytes (`FileWriter<1024 * 1024>` para uno).

---

Preguntas y respuestas relacionadas:

- [Writing data to a file in C++ - most efficient way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17370203/13419694)
- [Should C++ programmers use std::flush frequently?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694109/13419694)
- [How to get IOStream to perform better?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166263/13419694)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan completa información. Yo tengo poca experiencia con C, pero creo entender el concepto; no conocia sobre el uso del buffer por lo que me surgen algunas dudas. El buffer se sobreescribe cada vez que se hace la llamada?. En mi problema, se trata de una iteracion con un loop for que en cada pasada genera una linea de texto. Si lo voy almacenado en un buffer, me da la impresion que al final contendrá sólo la ultima linea… ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: Depende del tamaño del buffer. Si tus líneas son, por ejemplo de 100 caracteres y el buffer es de 1KiB (1024 bytes), en él entrarían 1024 / 100 = 10 líneas. A la línea 11 recién no tendría espacio suficiente y reiniciaría el buffer.